# Windows Phone | Restoring the application form background, when user trying to open application again

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, background-process

Whether there is such a way that helps to restore the application from the background when the user launches it from the menu again?

If this not possible please provide link to documentation.

P.S. I just want to see the same behavior as on Android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to directly do this with the SDK - it supports fast app resuming on the back key press, but when they launch it from the menu it launches it new.

You could manually keep track of application status, similar to what you would have done with pre-Mango tombstoning, and then resume yourself when the application is launched new. A little info: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2010/07/14/silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-tombstoning.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions Application_Deactivated,Application_Closing of App.xaml.cs

```
private void Application_Deactivated()

    {

         Save your application state in isolated storage.

    }
private void Application_Closing()

    {

         Delete application state from isolated storage.

    }
private void Application_Launching()

    {

        check if there is a application state stored in isolated storage.
        if yes then resume it 
        else start fresh 

    }
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: This not helps me to avoid splash screen again, but thanks for response)